# Optimal row/column pairing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, matching, pyomo, pairing

I encountered a problem while I was trying to match images with their correlation coefficient.

Say we have 5 thumbnails (a, b, c, d, e) and we need to find the best corresponding thumbnail for each one of them on another set of thumbnails (f, g, h, i, j). (One item cannot be re-used.)

For each possible pair, we compute the correlation coefficient (measurement of similarity).

```
     f     g     h     i     j
  |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
a | 0.5 | 0.7 |  0  |  0  |  0  |
  |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
b | 0.7 | 0.8 |  0  |  0  |  0  |
  |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
c |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  | 0.8 |
  |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
d |  0  |  0  | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 |
  |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
e |  0  | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.5 |  0  |
  |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
```

What I do :

- Find the max for each raw

  ```
       f     g     h     i     j
    |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  a |  0  | 0.7 |  0  |  0  |  0  |
    |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  b |  0  | 0.8 |  0  |  0  |  0  |
    |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  c |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  | 0.8 |
    |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  d |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  | 0.7 |
    |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  e |  0  |  0  | 0.7 |  0  |  0  |
    |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  ```
- Find the max for each column

  ```
        f     g     h     i     j
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   a |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   b |  0  | 0.8 |  0  |  0  |  0  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   c |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  | 0.8 |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   d |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   e |  0  |  0  | 0.7 |  0  |  0  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  ```
- Save those pairs in a table
- Create a mask where the raw and the column of each number in this last table are equal to zero

  ```
        f     g     h     i     j
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   a |  1  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   b |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   c |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   d |  1  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   e |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  ```
- Multiply the mask with the first table

  ```
       f     g     h     i     j
    |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  a | 0.5 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
    |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  b |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
    |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  c |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
    |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  d |  0  |  0  |  0  | 0.6 |  0  |
    |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  e |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
    |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
  ```
- Repeat the process until the matrix obtained at the second step is equal to zero

So at the end, the matching table looks like that :

```
        f     g     h     i     j
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   a |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   b |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   c |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   d |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
   e |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |
     |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
```

According the this method, the best pairs possible are :
(a,f), (b,g), (c,j), (d,i) and (e,h)

Now the question is :
Is there a better method?

Like for (a,b) and (f,g), wouldn't be better to add up their scores to find the best match?

Ex :

```
  (a,f) (b,g)
   0.5 + 0.7 = 1.2

  (a,g) (b,f)
   0.7 + 0.7 = 1.4

   1.4 > 1.2 => best pairs are (a,g) and (b,f)
   (As opposed to (a,f), (b,g) with the first method.)
```

If so, how to make it generalizable?

I hope that I've been clear enough to make you understand the problem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT :**

I found out that the Hungarian algorithm is much faster than the ILP solution provided by AirSquid.

I compared the Hungarian implementation of Scipy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html) with the ILP based solution.

After 1000 one-to-one matching iterations of a random 20x20 matrix I got :

| Method | ite/s |
| --- | --- |
| ILP solution | 4.06e-2 |
| Hungarian algorithm | 1.808e-5 |

From tests, I haven't seen any differences between those two methods.

Comment: Whether there is _a better method_ depends on what you consider _better_, e. g. which result is better - one with the maximum individual correlation, one with the maximal minimum correlation, one with the maximal sum of correlations, or …?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know which method I should use since I won't be able to get a perfect result. I guess what I can do it's to create a test dataset and try different methods in order to pick the better one? Also, for the maximum sum of correlation, I don't find an easy way to write it down. I might be overthinking it. How should I start?

Comment: Your problem is not well specified.  You didn't say whether or not one of the items could be re-used, but it appears from your solution that is implied.  Also, it isn't clear if it is more desirable to have a better grand sum of the correlations for best, or a maxi-min solution (maximize the minimum correlation).  Those might lead to different answers...  In either case, I don't think it would be too difficult to poke holes in your approach with counter-examples.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I'll edit my post to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trivial pairing model for most any math solver and can be formulated as an ILP.  If you wish to go this route in python, you have several choices (after learning a bit about LP/ILP formulation :) ).  I'm partial to `pyomo` but `pulp` and `or-tools` are also viable.  You will also need a solver engine.  There are several freebies out there, some are easier to install than others.  I believe `pulp` has a built-in solver, which is nice.

There is probably a dynamic programming solution to consider as well, but this is fast & easy.  For the examples I note in the problem below (a replica of the counter-example above and a random 20x20 matrix), optimal solutions are almost instantaneous.

```
# pairing

import pyomo.environ as pyo
import numpy as np

data = [[.99, .98, .97, .96, .95],
        [.98, .97, .96, .95, 0],
        [.97, .96, .95, 0,   0],
        [.96, .95, 0,   0,   0],
        [.95, 0,   0,   0,   0]]

#data = np.random.rand(20, 20)  #alternate random data for testing...

model = pyo.ConcreteModel('r-c pairings')

#re-label the data and push into a dictionary
labels = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
data = {(labels[r], labels[len(data) + c]) : data[r][c] 
            for r in range(len(data)) for c in range(len(data[0]))}

# pyomo components
model.R = pyo.Set(initialize = [k[0] for k in data.keys()])
model.C = pyo.Set(initialize = [k[1] for k in data.keys()])
model.corr = pyo.Param(model.R, model.C, initialize=data)
model.X = pyo.Var(model.R, model.C, within=pyo.Binary)  # select pairing (r, c)


# objective:  maximize overall value
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=pyo.summation(model.corr, model.X), sense=pyo.maximize)  #shortcut to ∑cX

# constraint:  only use each column value once
def single_use(m, c):
    return sum(model.X[r,c] for r in model.R) <= 1
model.C1 = pyo.Constraint(model.C, rule=single_use)

# constraint:  only use each row value once
def single_use_row(m, r):
    return sum(model.X[r,c] for c in model.C) <= 1
model.C2 = pyo.Constraint(model.R, rule=single_use_row)

# solve it...
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')  # <-- need to have this solver installed
result = solver.solve(model)
print(result)
pyo.display(model)
```

#### Output (from the smaller data run):

```
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 4.75
  Upper bound: 4.75
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 11
  Number of variables: 26
  Number of nonzeros: 51
  Sense: maximize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  Termination condition: optimal
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 1
      Number of created subproblems: 1
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.010313272476196289
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

Model r-c pairings

  Variables:
    X : Size=25, Index=X_index
        Key        : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        ('a', 'f') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('a', 'g') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('a', 'h') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('a', 'i') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('a', 'j') :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('b', 'f') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('b', 'g') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('b', 'h') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('b', 'i') :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('b', 'j') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('c', 'f') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('c', 'g') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('c', 'h') :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('c', 'i') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('c', 'j') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('d', 'f') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('d', 'g') :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('d', 'h') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('d', 'i') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('d', 'j') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('e', 'f') :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('e', 'g') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('e', 'h') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('e', 'i') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        ('e', 'j') :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary

  Objectives:
    obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Value
        None :   True :  4.75

  Constraints:
    C1 : Size=5
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          f :  None :  1.0 :   1.0
          g :  None :  1.0 :   1.0
          h :  None :  1.0 :   1.0
          i :  None :  1.0 :   1.0
          j :  None :  1.0 :   1.0
    C2 : Size=5
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          a :  None :  1.0 :   1.0
          b :  None :  1.0 :   1.0
          c :  None :  1.0 :   1.0
          d :  None :  1.0 :   1.0
          e :  None :  1.0 :   1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! It works very well (obviously). I've read about ILP, and I still have to read more. However, I'm a little bit stuck on the mathematical modeling of the two constraints. How would you write it mathematically? Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: The purpose of the two constraints is to only allow each row or column to be used once.  The first one, `C1`, sums up all of the binary values in the rows in R *for each* value in C.  The `pyomo` expression `Constraint(...)` calls the function with every member of the set that is the first element of that statement, so it creates |C| constraints of type C1.  You can see the result of those 5 equations in the output.  (I'd put it in LaTex, but that is not supported here)

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: In my opinion, we could call this constraint a bijection, couldn't we? I also found out that this problem can be solved with Hungarian's algorithm (if we model it as a graph problem). But I think the ILP method guarantees an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is broken for some cases.

For an example consider:

```
      f     g     
     |-----|-----|
   a | 0.9 | 0.8 |
     |-----|-----|
   b | 0.8 |  0  |
     |-----|-----|
```

For this case, the best solution is `ag` and `bf`, where the total score is "0.8 + 0.8 = 1.6". If you choose the maximum score first (`af`) you're forced to use `bg` as the second pair (as there's no other choice left), and that gives you a total score of "0.9 + 0 = 0.9", which is much worse.

Note that the same problem exists (and can be much worse) for 5 pairs. E.g. for an extreme case:

```
     f      g      h      i      j
  |------|------|------|------|------|
a | 0.99 | 0.98 | 0.97 | 0.96 | 0.95 |
  |------|------|------|------|------|
b | 0.98 | 0.97 | 0.96 | 0.95 |   0  |
  |------|------|------|------|------|
c | 0.97 | 0.96 | 0.95 |   0  |   0  |
  |------|------|------|------|------|
d | 0.96 | 0.95 |   0  |   0  |   0  |
  |------|------|------|------|------|
e | 0.95 |   0  |   0  |   0  |   0  |
  |------|------|------|------|------|
```

Here, "maximum first" leads to `af`, `bg`, `ch`, `di`, `ej` with a total score of 2.91; but the best solution is `ef`, `dg`, `ch`, `bi`, `aj` with a total score of 4.75.

To find the best pairings; you want to calculate the total for each possibility, then find the highest total. The simplest way to do that is with a brute force approach (literally, calculate a total for every possibility) but that has relatively high overhead.

Assuming a "nested loops" approach (e.g. where you have an outer loop iterating through the possibilities for `a`, an inner loop iterating through possibilities for `b`, ...; and where each inner loop can create a new "partial total" so that the inner-most loop can use the partial total rather than calculating the full total itself); I don't think there's a practical way to improve performance (without creating a risk of failing to find the best solution).

Comment: Thanks for your well-explained answer and for pointing out this broken case. If there is no other way than brute-forcing it, I will. Regards, C.

Comment: You are almost certainly going to get better performance using a solver and putting this into an Integer Linear Programming model.  If size gets "big" it might be worth the effort

Comment: It depends on what you call "big", I think I'll have to pair at most 20 thumbnails at a time. But for sure, it will still be worth digging a little bit into Integer Linear Programming since I don't know it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yes, you will need to do something other than brute force then.  As brute force for 20 is 20! options, which is 10^18.